# which api does dataloader uses when bulk api is not checked? What is the default API?

Tags: metadata-api, data-loader, bulk-api, dataloader.io

Which api does dataloader uses when bulk api is not checked? What is the default API ?

I could see explanation for using BULK API in dataloader, but what to know which api is used in default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Bulk API is not being used it uses [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/).
SOAP API is the oldest webservice SFDC API.

Page by the link above also provides details of other available APIs and explains when to use which.